# How do we know the average number per month of a table in sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Given these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DOWNLOAD 
( 
    PROFILE_ID INT, 
    DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE USER_PROFILE 
( 
    ID VARCHAR2(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1), 
);
```

How do we know the average number of downloads per month of a specific user (for example C1234) in a year (2020 for example)? For instance, if we downloaded 12 times in January, and 0 times in the remaining, we would have 1 download/month in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be

```
select avg(cnt) avg_cnt
from (select count(*) cnt, to_char(d.download_timestamp, 'yyyymm') yyyymm
      from download d
      where d.profile_id = :par_profile_id
        and extract (year from d.download_timestamp) = :par_yyyy
      group by to_char(d.download_timestamp, 'yyyymm')
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `DOWNLOAD` table and use two `GROUP BY`s at different level as follows:

```
SELECT PROFILE_ID, 
       AVG(CNT) AS AVG -- OR SUM(CNT)/12 IF EVERY MONTH DATA IS NOT AVAILABLE IN THE TABLE
FROM
(SELECT D.PROFILE_ID,
       COUNT(1) AS CNT
  FROM DOWNLOAD       D 
 WHERE D.DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP >= TO_DATE(:INPUT_YEAR,'YYYY')
   AND D.DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP < ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:INPUT_YEAR,'YYYY'),12)
 GROUP BY D.PROFILE_ID,
          TRUNC(D.DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP,'MON')
) GROUP BY PROFILE_ID;
```

If every month's records are not available for a user in the `DOWNLOAD` table for then you can use the `sum(cnt)/12` formula from the code.

Also, You should use the following conditions on the `DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP` column so that the `Index` of this column is used, if any.

```
D.DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP >= TO_DATE(:INPUT_YEAR,'YYYY')
AND D.DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP < ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:INPUT_YEAR,'YYYY'),12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic:

```
select count(*) / 12
from download d
where d.profile_id = :profile_id and
      to_char(d.download_timestamp, 'YYYY') = :year
```